# Issue with joining tables in LINQ when needing a left outer join type

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables:

```
Network_Clients
Clients
```

Network_Clients has three columns

```
networkClientID: Key
Name: Varchar
Description: Varchar
```

Client has 4 columns:

```
clientID: Key
networkClientId: FK to Network_Clients -> networkClientID
Name: Varchar
Description: Varchar
```

Clients Table:

```
clientID    networkClientID name    description
1                2          Client1 Client of Client2
2                3          Client1 Client of Client3
3                3          Client4 Client of Client3
4                1          Client4 Direct Placement Client
5                1          Client1 Direct Placement Client
```

Network Clients Table:

```
networkClientID name            description
1           Direct Placer       NULL
2           Client2             Network Client Client2
3           Client3             Network Client Client3
4           Test One            Test One Network Client
```

Here is my LINQ query:

```
from cn in Clients_Network
join c in Clients on cn.networkClientID equals c.networkClientID
select new { cn, c }
```

This returns everything but `Direct Placer` and `Test One` because neither of those have a linked field in the Clients table.

How can I get those two to show up?

Comment: `Direct Placer` does have `networkClientID` 1 which exists in the `Clients` table.

Comment: Yes, it is showing up but my test one is not.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [group join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (i.e. join...into):

```
from cn in Clients_Network
join c in Clients on cn.networkClientID equals c.networkClientID into g
from cc in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { cn, cc }
```

Thats an equivalent of left join in SQL

Comment: This works in LinqPad but now it is causing errors in my C# app, well it isn't causing them I just need to convert some things to nullable it said.

Comment: @JamesWilson if you need to return some property of Client, then you should check cc for null like this: `new { cn, clientId = (cc == null) ? null : (int?)cc.clientId }` (this is the case when default value returned if there is nothing to join)